# `az login` suddenly stopped working in my command prompt

Tags: azure, command-prompt, azure-cli

When I do az login in the command prompt opened with Administrator privileges, getting weird error which I didn't get this before:

```
Please select the account you want to log in with.
User cancelled the Accounts Control Operation.. Status: Response_Status.Status_UserCanceled, Error code: 0, Tag: 528315210
Please explicitly log in with:
az login
```

In Googling, I found the similar issue is reported in [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/26486) and Open State.
Can we have any alternative fix to this issue..!

Comment: Please edit your question and include the link to the GitHub issue you mentioned.

Comment: My bad. Forgot to attach the link. I have attached now and could you please upvote the question @GauravMantri

Comment: Thanks! I did not downvote the question. I would recommend opening a GitHub issue and reference this post and the other GitHub post there.

Answer (score 1):

Open Command Prompt as administrator and perform the below commands:

```bash
az config set core.allow_broker=false
az account clear
az login
```

- WAM based Login is not working completely.
- Do browser based Login from the Command Prompt as we do in a normal way.